# Lemma 2.4 in chapter 2 of Goerss Jardine Simplicial homotopy theory

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am having trouble with lemma 2.4 of the chapter of simplicial categories. I have a feeling there are mistakes in the proof or maybe typos. He wants to prove the 2.1.2 property of the definition of a simplicial category, that is **Hom**$_{C}(A,-)\colon C\to sSets$ is a right adjoint of $A\otimes-\colon sSets\to C$. The problem is I cannot understand why he takes an coequalizer of a simplicial set (and how this is even done). Moreover, in his notation, he has the notation **hom**$_{C}(A,B)$, where by assumption we have a map **hom**$_{C}(K,-)\colon C\to C$ and $K\in sSets$. However, since he has a tensor with $A$ in the previous line with the standard simplices, then it should be $A\in C$, so there is a problem with the definition of the functor **hom**$_{C}(A,B)$.

Comment: As far as "how this is even done," coequalizers are taken level-wise: the $n$-simplices in the coequalizer are the coequalizer (of ordinary sets) of the $n$-simplices.

Comment: What about the other questions?

Comment: Your question should be made more self-contained, i.e., without requiring the reader to open up a copy of Goerss-Jardine.  For example, what do you mean "tensor with $A$ in the previous line"? (Btw, you should be careful about distinguishing between boldfaced homs and regular homs - this should helpfully answer your second question.)

Comment: This is the notation of the book. If you google the book, you can find a copy because it is well-known.

Comment: When they say "For fixed $K \in \mathbf{S}$ ...", they mean "For all $K$ ...". So $\mathbf{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,B)$ is defined for any objects in the category.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I'm not sure what you mean here. Sure, coequalizers taken level-wise give coequalizers of simplicial sets, but what are we indexing over? What are the two morphisms that we are writing K as the coequalizer of.

Comment: One way to approach this is to avoid coequalizers and appeal to Lemma 2.1 in Chapter 1: every simplicial set is the colimit of representable functors, namely its simplices.

Answer (score 1):

They (there are two authors) are taking a coequalizer because, by assumption (2), the tensor product functor commutes with all colimits, and hence will commute with the coequalizer. The functor $\mathbf{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(K, \cdot)$ is a right adjoint by assumption, so it commutes with limits.